# Hide Custom Taxonomy title if not associated with another Custom Taxomony

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

Custom Post type named Business (Custom Fields (Contact Details, Business Name)) 
Taxonomy for Type of Business (What they do (Cleaning, Auto))
Taxonomy for Location of Business; example Melbourne --> South Melbourne, Perth --> North Perth

What I'm trying to do is you click on a Type of Business(Cleaning) and on that page it will display the Parent Location Title (Melbourne) and under that the child locations (South Melbourne) and under that all the Business Titles that is associated with the Type of Business(Cleaning) that I have clicked on.

I have this all working, however it's displaying the Location of Business parent (Melbourne) even if it isn't associated with any posts in the category (cleaning) that I'm viewing. How can I hide these? Currently looping get_terms within get_terms and than calling the Post Type Titles.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer from another site after hours of searching! - http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/10819

```
<?php

    // List posts by the terms for a custom taxonomy of any post type



        $post_type = 'product';

        $tax = 'products';

        $tax_args = array(

            'order' => 'DESC',

            'parent' => 0

        );

        // get all the first level terms only

        $tax_terms = get_terms( $tax, $tax_args );

        if ($tax_terms) {

            foreach ($tax_terms  as $tax_term) { // foreach first level term

                // print the parent heading

                ?>

                <h4 class="parent-term"><?php echo $tax_term->name; ?></h4>



                <?php

                // get all its children

                $child_terms = ""; // first ensure this var is empty

                $child_terms = get_terms ( $tax, array('order' => 'DESC', 'parent' => $tax_term->term_id) );

                // store an array of child terms slug

                $child_terms_array = array();

                foreach ($child_terms as $child_term){

                    $child_terms_array[] = $child_term->slug;

                }



                // first of all, print the posts of the parent, but excluding the one which are also into a child term

                $parent_args="";            

                $parent_args = array(

                    'post_type' => $post_type,

                    'tax_query' => array(

                        'relation' => 'AND',

                        array(

                            'taxonomy' => $tax,               

                            'field' => 'slug',                    

                            'terms' => $tax_term->slug,    

                            'include_children' => false,           

                            'operator' => 'IN'                   

                          ),

                        array(

                            'taxonomy' => $tax,               

                            'field' => 'slug',                    

                            'terms' => $child_terms_array,    

                            'include_children' => false,           

                            'operator' => 'NOT IN'                   

                          )

                        ),

                    'post_status' => 'publish',

                    'posts_per_page' => 6,

                    'order' => 'ASC',

                );

                // query the posts

                $parent_query = null;

                $parent_query = new WP_Query($parent_args);



                if( $parent_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

                    <ul>

                        <?php while ( $parent_query->have_posts() ) : $parent_query->the_post(); ?>

                            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

                            <?php the_title(); ?>

                            </a>

                            </li>

                        <?php endwhile; // end of loop ?>       

                    </ul>



                <?php endif; // if have_posts()

                wp_reset_query();



                // if any, foreach child term, query the posts

                if ( !empty($child_terms) ){            

                    foreach ($child_terms as $child_term){

                        $child_args="";         

                        $child_args = array(

                            'post_type' => $post_type,

                            'tax_query' => array(

                                array(

                                    'taxonomy' => $tax,               

                                    'field' => 'slug',                    

                                    'terms' => $child_term->slug,    

                                    'include_children' => false,           

                                    'operator' => 'IN'                   

                                  )

                                ),

                            'post_status' => 'publish',

                            'posts_per_page' => 6,

                            'order' => 'ASC',

                        );

                        // query the posts  

                        $child_query = null;

                        $child_query = new WP_Query($child_args);



                        if( $child_query->have_posts() ) : ?>



                            <h4 class="child-term"><?php echo $child_term->name; ?></h4>    

                            <ul>

                                <?php while ( $child_query->have_posts() ) : $child_query->the_post(); ?>

                                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">

                                    <?php the_title(); ?>

                                    </a>

                                    </li>

                                <?php endwhile; // end of loop ?>



                            </ul>



                        <?php endif; // if have_posts()



                        wp_reset_query();

                    } // end foreach #child_terms

                }



            } // end foreach #parent_term

        }

        ?>
```